# PaperJs looping throught path's point position gives Cannot read property 'point' of undefined

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to achive a fluctuant animation effect using PaperJS.

I have a path cloned 2 times and each have 4 points, a `setInterval` animates every points in every path in a for cicle but `for i>=2` i get this `error "Cannot read property 'point' of undefined".` Infact watching animation I can see that not all points are animated.

This is a codepen demo: https://codepen.io/mrk1977_02/pen/QWLgVMp?editors=0010

```
var path1;
var path2;
var path3;
var startX = 100;
var endX = 100;
var minValX = 30;
var maxValX = 30;
var minValY = 10;
var maxValY = 10;
var minVel = 3;
var maxVel = 3.5;
var interval = 1000;
var time = 2;
var segmentsArray = [[30, 92], [37, 45], [90, 50], [80, 120]];
var offsetVal1;
var offsetVal2;
var scaleArr = [1.4,1.3,1.2];
var ease = SlowMo.ease.config(0.1, 0.3, false);
//var ease = Power4.easeOut; 
var circle_points1=null;
var circle_points2=null;
var circle_points3=null;

window.onload = function() {
        paper.setup('myCanvas');    
    path1 = new Path({
      segments: segmentsArray,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 0.1,
      closed: true,
      opacity:0
    });

  path1.fullySelected = false;
  path1.position.x += startX;
  path1.position.y += startX;
  path1.smooth();
  path1.simplify(1);
  path1.scale(scaleArr[0]);

  path2 = path1.clone();
  //path2.smooth();
  path2.scale(scaleArr[1]);

  path3 = path2.clone();
  //path3.smooth();
  path3.scale(scaleArr[2]);

  path1.fillColor = '#ececec';
  path1.strokeWidth = 10;
  path1.strokeColor = '#ddd';

  setTimeout(initFadeIn, interval);
  setInterval(shapeAnimation, interval);
}

function initFadeIn(){
  var ease = Power4.easeOut;
  TweenMax.to(path1, time, { opacity: 1, ease: ease, force3D: true});
  TweenMax.to(path2, time, { opacity: 1, ease: ease, force3D: true});
  TweenMax.to(path3, time, { opacity: 1, ease: ease, force3D: true});
}

function shapeAnimation(){

  var timeShape = getRandomArbitrary(minVel, maxVel);

  for(var i=0; i<segmentsArray.length; i++){

      circle_points1 = path1.segments[i].point;
      circle_points2 = path2.segments[i].point;
      circle_points3 = path3.segments[i].point;
      //console.log(path1.segments[i].point.x);


      var minX = segmentsArray[i][0] - minValX;
      var maxX = segmentsArray[i][0] + maxValX;

      var minY = segmentsArray[i][1] - minValY;
      var maxY = segmentsArray[i][1] + maxValY;

      gapX = getRandomArbitrary(minX, maxX);
      offsetValX = startX+gapX;
      //console.log(offsetValX);

      gapY = getRandomArbitrary(minY, maxY);
      offsetValY = gapY+startX;

      TweenMax.to(circle_points1, timeShape, { x: offsetValX, /*y: offsetValY,*/ ease: ease, force3D: true});
      TweenMax.to(circle_points2, timeShape, { x: offsetValX, /*y: offsetValY,*/ ease: ease, force3D: true});
      TweenMax.to(circle_points3, timeShape, { x: offsetValX, /*y: offsetValY,*/ ease: ease, force3D: true});
  }
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    var val = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your call to `path1.simplify(1);`.
This actually removes some segments from your path. And later, when you try to iterate over 4 segments, the paths only contains 2.
So `path1.segments[i]` is undefined when `i = 2` and `path1.segments[i].point` throws an error.
The solution is to remove the line `path1.simplify(1);`.
You already call `path1.smooth();` which is enough in your case as it does the smoothing job and it won't remove any segment so your script will work as expected.

Comment: Yes you're right infact I removed it. I also animated handles and not points to get a better animation. It works